# Admin panel to keep signed in till logout

Tags: php, session, cookies, opencart

In opencart version 2 admin panel how should we allow admin user to keep login till signout.
I have tried with session life time . Whether this problem related to session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a couple of things that can log an admin out:

1. the session can expire
2. the cookie can expire (which is partially connected to the session)
3. the token parameter could be incorrect or changed

### How to fix

1. to increase the lifetime of a session in file 'admin/index.php' add this code to the top of the file right after `<?php`

```php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '315360000');
```

where 315360000 is 10 years in seconds.

2. to increase the lifetime of the cookie in OpenCart you actually don't need to do anything if you added the code above for the session because opencart uses that lifetime to set the lifetime for the cookie.
3. if you have two admin panels opened, you may face a situation where the tokens don't match. if the token in the url doesn't match the token in the session, you will be logged out. so keep that in mind.

let me know if that helped.

Comment: Yes this option is worked . But inorder to enable admin login we need to do one more step.Controller ->common->login -> index we need to include if condition with if($this->user->islogged() && isset($this->session->data['token'])). Then admin keep login is working fine. Thank you for the valuable suport

Comment: Cool, glad you got it!